# How to update shipment tracking info with spree api call

Tags: curl, spree

Using Spree 2.0.x how is it possible to update a shipments tracking details?

Here's a curl example that should update a shipment's tracking to 'yeah'. But it doesn't seem to do anything. What's wrong with it?

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "X-Spree-Token: b79756519374randomtokenb79756519374" -d "shipment\[tracking\]=yeah" http://url.com/api/orders/W647803480/shipments/H10788414786
```

In the server log I see the appropriate request;

```
Started PUT "/api/orders/W647803480/shipments/H10788414786"
```

but the only data that gets updated is the 'updated_at' field of the order.

I've also tried sending "tracking=yeah" instead of the above but no joy.

So - how is it possible to use the API to set the tracking info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in order to update shipment attributes it's necessary to use `/ready` in the url.

For the above example;

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "X-Spree-Token: b79756519374randomtokenb79756519374" -d "shipment\[tracking\]=yeah" http://url.com/api/orders/W647803480/shipments/H10788414786/ready
```

will work.